# Filter by multiple properties with optional properties?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to filter an array of products by two json properties, `isExtinguisher` & `brand`, the `isExtinguisher` property is an easy one, just a checkbox and the filter for a `<select>` like this:

```
ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.filtered_products | filter : { isExtinguisher : vm.isExtinguisher } : true"
```

What I'm having trouble with is the `brand` filtering, I have another `<select>` for the brands, it is binded to `vm.current_brand` what I would like is that if `vm.current_brand` has value then the products `<select>` will be filtered, if not then it will display all the products of all brands.

Doing the following only displays products when selecting a brand:

```
ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.filtered_products | filter : { isExtinguisher : vm.isExtinguisher, brand : vm.current_brand } : true"
```

But when no brand is selected, then no product is displayed, and what I want is that if no brand is selected, then all products will be display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
filter : vm.getFilter() : true
```

and define getFilter() that way in your controller:

```
vm.getFilter = function() {
    var result = {
        isExtinguisher : vm.isExtinguisher
    };
    if (vm.current_brand) {
        result.brand = vm.current_brand;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a custom filter then?

Comment: You could also do that, yes. I don't see why it would be better, though.